# Excel - Refresh and Validate Data From SQL (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, named-ranges

I'm using office 2013 and SQLServer 2008 R2. I have an Excel VBA proc that inserts a list of commissions for sales into a database. One of the columns is SalesRepID, which clearly has to be valid. When it was written, we had a fairly static sales team, but we've since acquired two other companies who do less specialized work, so there's a quite a bit of change in the sales force now.

The current methods has a list of sales repID's and names in sorted named range, which is then used as validation criteria: the user is given a list of sales reps in drop down list in Excel and when they select one, it uses VLookup to insert the SalesRepID in a hidden cell. This is then used in the insert operation.

What I want to do now is give the users a refresh button (and ideally run the refresh on open). Some of the billers work at home at the weekend, so this needs to be able to work offline (obviously, if a new rep is added and they haven't refreshed they won't see the new rep).

I don't want to have to define anything like ODBC sources on a user's physical machine

I'm trying to figure out the way to solve this. One way is to add a refresh button that will execute a query, insert the current list of sales reps and update the range (or use a dynamic range) to be the current no of records returned. (I'm assuming I can update a named range's address, or that a dynamic range will update if the data is inserted from a SQL query)

For example:

Initial Range

```
1 Tom
2 Dick
3 Harry
```

SalesReps range = A1:B3

User Hits Refresh: Deletes old ranges contents. insert new list

New Range

```
1 Tom
2 Dick
3 Harry
4 Fred
```

SalesReps range = A1:B4

Can anyone think of a better way to this?

Regards

Mark

Comment: What have you done till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this for your dynamic range

```
Dim LastRow as integer
    LastRow = Sheets("yoursheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A1:B" & LastRow).name = "SalesReps"
```

The code works in a slightly unintuitive way.     `Cells(Rows.Count, "A")` finds the very last cell on the sheet in column A (row 1048576 or something).

`End(xlUp).Row` is the equivalent of pressing ctrl+up from that cell and returning the row number of the first cell containing information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked great, but not sure I understand why. My initial range is I6:J6. I obviously changed the refs in your example to match my range, but not sure about xlUp. I would have thought starting from first row and using xlDown would have been solution. Does your example start from end of entire sheet and look up from there? Just trying to understand. Thanks Mark